# DataType of ppPasteMetaFilePicture does not copy map from Excel to PowerPoint

Tags: excel, maps, powerpoint

I am able to copy a large range from Excel including multiple charts and tables.  However, it does not copy the map produced by the Excel Map Process.  It copies the area of the map but does not copy the map itself.  I am using DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture

```
   Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject

 'Look for existing instance
    On Error Resume Next
    Set newPowerPoint = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

'Let's create a new PowerPoint
    If newPowerPoint Is Nothing Then
        Set newPowerPoint = New PowerPoint.Application
    End If
'Make a presentation in PowerPoint
    If newPowerPoint.Presentations.Count = 0 Then
        newPowerPoint.Presentations.Add
    End If

'Show the PowerPoint
    newPowerPoint.Visible = True
```

a lot of code followed by

Range("A1:N36").Select
    Selection.Copy
                newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutObject
            newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
            Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
            activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select

Comment: Is the output from the Excel Map Process a metafile (EMF or SVG), or is it a bitmap (PNG, JPG, etc.)? If it's a bitmap. it will never paste as a metafile.

Comment: I am using the filled map chart type if that helps.  My input is a file with all of the states in one column and 0s and 1s in the other.  I get a US map as the output.

Comment: @JohnKorchok thanks for your assistance.  Perhaps, I need to make a separate copy of the map.  I appreciate all the help that you can provide.